# How to Convert mmddyyyy into date format in dataweave application/xml

Tags: mule, dataweave

I am converting string `"11232017"` (*mmddyyyy*) into date format in dataweave. If I give the output as json or java, it is converting correctly but application/xml is converting it into *yyyy-mm-dd*.

code:

```
%output application/xml
%var a ="12182013"
```

---

```
k:((a as :date {format : "MMddyyyy"} )
```

Answer (score 2):

I am getting the date as per MM/dd/yyy with below expression:

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/xml
---
{
    data: {
        value: payload as :date {format: "MMddyyyy" } as :string {format: "MM/dd/yyyy"}
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for replying gunjan, but at last format is as string which is failing on target side because of date format restriction,
I have to have date format with MM/dd/yyyy

Comment: can you try below expression: value: payload as :date {format: "MMddyyyy" } as :string {format: "MM/dd/yyyy"} as :date {format: "MM/dd/yyyy" }

Answer (score 1):

For printing in json or xml it is always better to put it in string format not the Date object. You can either convert your string to date then again date to string using required format or have your string with the required format.